# Read and write CSV file using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

I have csv file with contents below

```
heading1,heading2,

Name1,Name2,
```

If I select name in heading1, that value should be updated in CSV file.

```
   <select id="heading1" >  
         <option value="">Select</option>
         <option value="Nmae1">Nmae1</option>
         <option value="Nmae2">Nmae2</option>
    </select>
<select id="heading1" >  
     <option value="">Select</option>
     <option value="Nmae1">Nmae1</option>
     <option value="Nmae2">Nmae2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: See [Php and javascript code to modify a csv file entries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23106637/php-and-javascript-code-to-modify-a-csv-file-entries). Research will turn up more information.

Comment: I tried all the possibility's tried to search it in google and stackoverflow but no luck..that why I created new question ..@Traktor53

Comment: Maybe this can get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031719/read-csv-file-with-javascript-into-a-key-value-pair-array

Comment: I can read text from file and I don't know how to update file using javascript
Below code can be used to read and display content. I want to update as well . 
<script>
  jQuery 
    .ajax({
      url: './files/canmsg.txt',
      dataType: 'text'
    })
    .error(function(){
      console.warn('An error occurred whilst loading the file', arguments);
    })
    .done(function(res){
      jQuery.each(res.split(/\r?\n/g), function(i, v){
        jQuery('#canmess1').append('<p>' + v + '</p>');
  
      });
    })
  ;
   
</script>

Comment: My question is simple I have a CSV file .. How to update particular values in CSC file using Javascript or ajax or with anyone ..